How to interleave columns in sqlite
In SQLITE I have a table with three columns like so:
X Y Z
_____
1,2,A
1,3,B
3,4,C

I want what follows, order of the rows does not matter.
U Z
___
1 A
2 A
1 B
3 B
3 C
4 C

So then I can GROUP BY U and AVG(Z).
I tried a UNION but that is a bad way for me to go. I need something other than a UNION to get this done.

In SQLite, a union might be the easiest way to achieve what you want here:
SELECT U, AVG(Z) AS Z_AVG
FROM (
    SELECT X AS U, Z FROM yourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Y, Z FROM yourTable
) t
GROUP BY U
ORDER BY U;

